# How to link Boost library with CMake (on a cluster if boost is in non-standard location)?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have a strange problem, when I try to build a simple Boost test program on a cluster. 
On my machine, everything works just fine.

First the example:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "boost/program_options.hpp"

namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main( int argc , char* argv[] ) {

  po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
  desc.add_options()
  ("help", "produce help message")
  ("greet", po::value<std::string>()->default_value("World"), "the greeting")
  ;

  po::variables_map vm;
  po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);

  std::cout << "Hello, " << vm["greet"].as<std::string>() << "!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

And the CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(boost_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS program_options)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

if(Boost_FOUND)
    add_executable(boost_test ${SOURCE_FILES})
    target_include_directories(boost_test PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(boost_test PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif(Boost_FOUND)
```

I use cmake like

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" /path/to/code
make
```

The error I get is a undefined reference error during linking:

```
Linking CXX executable boost_test
CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options13variables_mapixERKSs[_ZNK5boost15program_options13variables_mapixERKSs]+0x1f): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const'
```

and so on ...

So I thought that maybe the installation of boost is not correct and I tried to write a makefile myself.

```
boost-test-1: ../code/main.cpp
    g++ ../code/main.cpp -o boost-test-1 -lboost_program_options

boost-test-2: ../code/main.cpp
    g++ ../code/main.cpp -o boost-test-2 /some/fancy/cluster/path/certainly/non/standard/Boost/lib/libboost_program_options.so
```

Both ways to build the program work fine. But what cmake is doing is basically the following: first, build a object file, second link the object file and the library together and that fails.

```
boost-test-3: ../code/main.cpp
    /usr/bin/c++    -I/some/fancy/cluster/path/certainly/non/standard/Boost/include  -std=c++11   -o main.cpp.o -c ../code/main.cpp
    /usr/bin/c++    -std=c++11   main.cpp.o  -o boost-test-3 /some/fancy/cluster/path/certainly/non/standard/Boost/lib/libboost_program_options.so
```

As already mentioned, on my computer all described ways to build the program work, but on the cluster, the cmake way unfortunately fails. The problem is that I have another larger project that uses cmake and I am looking for a way to build it on that particular cluster.

Do you have any idea what could cause the problem and how to solve it?
Thank you!

---

Update: This is the whole output of the build process. I shortened the paths to cmake and boost to "path/to/cmake" and "path/to/boost" to make it shorter and better readable, but it is the same long path as described above.

```
$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../code/
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Boost version: 1.61.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   program_options
-- Boost include directories (Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS): /path/to/Boost/include
-- Link directories for Boost libraries (Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS): /path/to/Boost/lib
-- Boost component libraries to be linked (Boost_LIBRARIES): /path/to/Boost/lib/libboost_program_options.so
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/test/build

$ make VERBOSE=1
/path/to/CMake/bin/cmake -H/home/test/code -B/home/test/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/path/to/CMake/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/test/build/CMakeFiles /home/test/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/test/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/test/build'
cd /home/test/build && /path/to/CMake/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/test/code /home/test/code /home/test/build /home/test/build /home/test/build/CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "/home/test/build/CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "/home/test/build/CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "/home/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "/home/test/build/CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target boost_test
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/test/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/test/build'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -I/path/to/Boost/include  -std=c++11   -o CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/test/code/main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable boost_test
/path/to/CMake/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++11   CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/main.cpp.o  -o boost_test /path/to/Boost/lib/libboost_program_options.so 
CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options13variables_mapixERKSs[_ZNK5boost15program_options13variables_mapixERKSs]+0x1f): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const'
CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::basic_command_line_parser(int, char const* const*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC2EiPKPKc[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC5EiPKPKc]+0x76): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::extra_parser(boost::function1<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::string const&>)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE12extra_parserENS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE12extra_parserENS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE]+0x33): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::set_additional_parser(boost::function1<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::string const&>)'
CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > boost::program_options::to_internal<std::string>(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options11to_internalISsEESt6vectorISsSaISsEERKS2_IT_SaIS5_EE[_ZN5boost15program_options11to_internalISsEESt6vectorISsSaISsEERKS2_IT_SaIS5_EE]+0x46): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::to_internal(std::string const&)'
CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscEE]+0x40): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool) const'
CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::string, char>::name() const':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE4nameEv[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE4nameEv]+0x32): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg'
CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::string, char>::xparse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&) const':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEE[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueISscE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEE]+0x7a): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, std::string*, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [boost_test] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/test/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/boost_test.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/test/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Do you know *where* "on the cluster" that Boost is installed? And you have read about [the FindBoost module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html), especially about the "hints" that tells it where it might be able to find Boost?

Comment: Usually `libboost_program_options.so` is a symbolic link. Are you sure it is not broken?

Comment: @some programmer dude: yes I do. I probably didn't point out that clearly: cmake finds the boost installation and Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS and Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS contain the correct paths. However, the linking fails...

Comment: That makes sense. If you run a verbose make (`make VERBOSE=1`) and look at the actual commands being executed, are the correct flags and libraries used when linking?

Comment: @Amadeus: it seems that libboost_program_options.so is not a symbolic link. I tried if [ -L libboost_program_options.so ]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi (is there a better way? ;) ) and I get "no".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: make verbose yields basically what I used in the last makefile example. target boost-test-3.

Comment: @Fabian I usually use the old and good `ls -l`. On my system I've got: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 jan  1 17:22 /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so -> libboost_program_options.so.1.63.0` where the `->` denotes a symbolic link. The good part of this is that it shows you the boost version too. Take a look and see if the APIs are compatibles. Ah, you must see, in this case, if `libboost_program_options.so.1.63.0` exists too

Comment: Regarding the comment from @Amadeus about "versions", this could be potentially important. Are there perhaps multiple installations of Boost? Perhaps you use the headers from one installation and the library from another?

Comment: @Amadeus there is a file libboost_program_options.so.1.61.0 but it is also no symbolic link.
It is possible to load different modules with different boost versions, but at the moment there is only boost 1.61.0 loaded.
Moreover, there is the file libboost_program_options.a, also no link.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But if there are links missing, or different versions, shouldn't then all attempts to build the program fail? And not just the one with cmake?

Comment: @Fabian In your edit, have you changed your path to `/path/to/Boost/`? Because this path is very strange

Comment: @Amadeus I am sorry for the confusion. This should actually be the same as in the post above. I just wanted to shorten it for better readability.

Comment: Are `gcc++` and `/usr/bin/c++` refers to the **same** compiler? (I see both are GNU, but it could be different versions issue or whatever). I am unsure whether executable's "2-step" building may change something, but options `-std=c++11` and `-I.../non/standard/Boost/include` definitely may. Can you try these options in your successfull tests?

Comment: @Tsyvarev That was the solution! We loaded the module for gcc-5.4 but /usr/bin/c++ was still gcc-4.8. When we set the cxx compiler for cmake to gcc-5.4 the build process still failed, since we also use CUDA and per default the host code is not forwarded to the cxx compiler but the c compiler, which was still gcc-4.8. So after setting CUDA_HOST_COMPILER to CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER it now works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Amadeus, Someprogrammerdude and Tsyvarev for leading me in the right direction here :)

In fact, it was a compiler issue: The default compiler on the cluster was gcc-4.8.5, which cannot handle the latest Boost versions. Therefore, we loaded a module for gcc-5.4 but /usr/bin/gcc was still gcc-4.8.5. When we set the cxx compiler for cmake to gcc-5.4 the build process still failed, since we also use CUDA and per default the host code is not forwarded to the cxx compiler but the c compiler, which was still gcc-4.8.5. So after setting CUDA_HOST_COMPILER to CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER it works fine now.